# Classifying a log file in bash

Tags: text-processing

I have a log file that includes the time, the ip, the date and the status, and the status is either an error or a warning.

Collect each log in a separate text file according to the status, either error or warning, and send these text files as an automated email. I am confused with attaching a text file to an email, and how to actually send an email via linux. I am currently trying to use the "mail" utility.

```
[Fri Sep 09 10:42:29.902022 2011] [core:error]
[Fri Sep 09 10:43:29.902022 2011] [core:warning]
[Fri Sep 09 10:38:29.902022 2011] [core:warning]...
```

Comment: Two groups of what? Two log files? One log file but easily distinguishable sets of messages? Please provide an example (in your question) of the sort of results you're looking for.

Comment: Two groups of what?

Comment: 2 groups of config files, or text files

Comment: Please put that clarification [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/369289/edit). Not here in the comments.

Comment: a mailing group? are you sending emails, or creating mailing lists?

Comment: Um. You've just changed the question's meaning. What relates a mailing group to the status of entries in a log file? Please update your question to provide an example of what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply view them using grep filter like this:
`grep '\[core:warning\]' /var/log/file | less`

If you want to have two separate files then it is possible by creating fifo special file, then feeding it with your original log file and filtering output with grep process sending final output to new file.

Comment: @roaima Should work like a charm right now (missing backslashes)